# Temporarily Redirect domain to another server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ip, domain

I have a domain pointing to an Apache2 server (Call it Server 1).  I would like to be able to quickly point that domain to another server of a different IP number (Call it server 2) by adjusting Server 1's configuration without changing anything on GoDaddy.  Server 1 has Virtualmin installed on it, if there's a convenient way to make it happen through there; the goal is to have this be a quick, temporary adjustment to demo some material I have on Server 2.

If this is not possible for the domain itself, would it be possible to do it with a subdomain?

Any ideas on how to best go about this would be appreciated.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your dns hosted at godaddy or are they just your registrar?

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek thanks for the reply; they're just my registrar.  Both servers I'm using here are through ChicagoVPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit your dns zone quick and flip the ip address over to the other server. You might want to set the TTL small-ish like 600 (10 minutes) if it will let you and you don't plan on having the domain name on that IP very long. As long as the NS records in the zone editor stay the same on the dnsd and at your registrar that shouldn't be a big deal at all.

Caveat: make sure any CNAME records you have referencing that domain name can also move over (like mail.example.com). You may need to change those CNAME records slightly (ex, point to a subdomain you assigned to the old IP) as needed to keep pointed to the same IP.

Comment: Perfect!  Funny; I gave that trick a shot earlier in webmin but I didn't realize I had to click apply in the upper right-hand corner.  Much obliged sir.

Answer (score 0):

yust run 2 different, switchable configs on Server 1: one live and one that ProxyPassReverse to your second server. you could also run your demo.example.com on Server 1 permanently on a different port, beeing accessible all the time. no need to adjust/wair for DNS - updates.

the second method would involve iptables-redirects but might be a bit overload.